# Android Vuforia camera rotation incorrect when Auto Rotation is enabled

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Facing an issue with a Unity AR app on certain Android devices, including the Pixel 6, where if Auto Rotation is enabled, the camera view is not rotated correctly. The app should be in landscape mode, but the feed from the camera is not rotating to landscape. Turning off Auto Rotation in the phone's settings fixes the issue. Not seeing this issue on iOS.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I would recommend to file a ln issue here with a repro case https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine